# Fermat primality test

Tags: java, performance, primes

Here is a simple working Java implementation of primality test for Fermat numbers. Is there something that I could change in code to achieve a better running time?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class FPT 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double n;
        n = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

        int e = (int)n;

        if (e > 1)
        {
            double m = Math.pow(2,n);
            int k = (int)m;
            BigInteger F;
            F = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(k).add(BigInteger.ONE);
            BigInteger s = new BigInteger ("8");
            double o = 1;
            double a = n - o ;
            double b = Math.pow(2,a) - o;
            int c = (int)b;

            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i ++)
            {
                 s=s.pow(4).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(4).multiply(s.pow(2))).add(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).mod(F);
            }

            if (s.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            {
                System.out.println("prime");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("composite");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("exponent must be greater than one");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `double` when you are working with integers. You do realize doubles aren't infinite precision.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29

Comment: That link doesn't say anything. `double` only supports up to around 18 digits. You should be using BigInteger throughout.  Also `o` is a terrible variable to use because it looks like zero. If you mean a constant 1, just use 1 instead of a variable.

Comment: Have you looked at [Pepin's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test) for testing primality?

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue I know that such test exists but I am interested in Java implementation of this LLT-like primality test for Fermat numbers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still can't quite figure out the way to this algorithm =/. But, from the Java point of view, you can gain 9-10% by changing your loop to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= c; i ++) {
    BigInteger temp = s.pow(2);
    s = temp.pow(2).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(4).multiply(temp)).add(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).mod(F);
}
```

...because the cached value can be used twice there.

Otherwise, the code is hard to read. It's not self explanatory nor commented and could be written in a better way - for a human to read, at least. But none of those changes would affect performance in any way.

**EDIT**: Additional 17% thanks to @Landei in comments.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= c; i ++) {
    BigInteger temp = s.modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(2), F);
    s = temp.pow(2).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(4).multiply(temp)).add(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
}
s = s.mod(F);
```

That takes advantage of `modPow()` method which can do `pow().mod()` in one step without much additional overhead. Since the `mod` is not necessary to have every time, it is enough to do it in `temp` (that actually propagates twice into the resulting expression) and enjoy the substantial speedup. You *need* to add one proper mod after the loop is done, though.

Comment: Would it be better to use `s.multiply(s)` instead of `s.pow(2)` ?

Comment: Tried that one, it's actually making things worse - at least on my `JDK7 -server`.

Comment: `BigInteger temp = s.modPow(2,F);` may help a little bit, too.

Comment: That was, actually, a very good idea! Gonna edit it into answer - if you would like to make your own, feel free to do so :)

Comment: btw I additionally tried to refactor the expression from `(s^4 - 4*s^2 + 2)` to `(s^2 - 4)*(s^2) +2` (that is much worse) and to `(s^2 - 4)^2 - 2` (that is absolutely the same). I tried changing the multiplication to `.shiftLeft(2)` and some other stuff, none of those work. How could I miss this one?!

Comment: @Slanec Is it possible to estimate a  time needed to test primality of the number `2^(2^(33))+1` using this Java code ?

Comment: A crapload. I don't believe you can compute such a beastly thing on a regular desktop machine. My 5 years old notebook takes 2 seconds to compute F(12) and 13 seconds to compute F(13). The number of needed iterations rises exponentially, so does the Fermat number. The F(33) would need a million times more iterations than F(13). The F(33) has 2.58*10^9 digits(!!!) - that's 1 GB of memory just to hold it! And you want to do 4 billion computations on that, every one taking 5 creations of such a beast. My most optimistic guess is 4 years with a new and shiny computer.

Comment: @Slanec [It is worth to try](https://www.eff.org/awards/coop)

Comment: Uuuh. Nice. I'd try 2^2^29 - 2^2^32 first, as they also are within range. If haven't tried them, that is :). And get a new and great CPU. You could, in the loop, write out `if (i % someconstant == 0) System.out.println(i);` just to see your speed of calculation to do an educated estimate.

Comment: @Slanec Those numbers are  composite for sure...the smallest Fermat number with unknown primality status is a F(33)...by the way see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10007327/964331)...

Answer (score 0):

Some basic optimalizations:

The reverse `for`: `for (int i = c - 1; i >= 0; c--)` should be a little faster. Java has a special instruction for comparing with zero. No need to compare two local variables.

Another thing is that every method call is slow. Better to put every constant `BigInteger.valueOf(4)` to a local variable first: `BigInteger four = BigInteger.valueOf(4);`

I don't guarantee a faster code - with modern Java optimalizations and JIT it's possible that these optimalizations are done automatically by compiler.